# Html to Pdf library in Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, pdf-generation, azure-functions, .net-standard

Azure functions apparently doesn't yet support `System.Drawing` ([sanbox info](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#win32ksys-user32gdi32-restrictions)). Running a function with a dependency on it throws the following message:

```
System.Drawing is not supported on this platform.
```

I was originally using [Select.HtmlToPdf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Select.HtmlToPdf/) in a WebApp to create PDF documents from HTML. But, since moving the PDF generation to an Azure function, that is no longer an option.

Also, the reccomended library is `wkhtmltopdf`, but that doesn't seem to have a `.netstandard2.0` version.

How would you accomplish PDF generation using Azure Functions (C#)?

---

Update: the function is running on an S1 - App Service Plan.

Update2: using the method shown on [OdeToCode](https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2018/02/14/pdf-generation-in-azure-functions-v2.aspx) gives the error `Qt: Could not initialize OLE (error 80010106)`

Comment: Are you running in consumption plan mode? If so the sandbox is more restrictive you need to run in app service plan mode to mimic web app. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale

Comment: please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51907024/7073340)

Comment: @Ken W: I’m running it in app service mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point I created a new `netcore2.0` Azure AppService API that supports `Select.HtmlToPdf` and will probably move this functionality to a container if it still doesn't work with `netcore3.0` in a little while.
The function just calls the API with some parameters and can wait for the PDF generation async.

As [Jerry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9191057/jerry-liu) has mentioned, it might work with [DinkToPdf](https://github.com/rdvojmoc/DinkToPdf). However, the template html docs must not contain JavaScript, so this solution is not valid for my use-case.

Answer (score 2):

I made a solution recently generating PDF files from HTML pages. I also had problems finding an appropriate framework that would run within an Azure function. But i found that using wkhtmltopdf, i could generate PDF documents from HTML pages.

Here is a link:
https://wkhtmltopdf.org/

I found that the minimum app service plan i could run with was: B1 service plan. This won't work with consumption plan. I did this using the experimental Powershell mode, but the same should be possible using C# or any other of the supported languages.

I am not thrilled with the PDF output, but it gets the job done. There are a lot of options to use, but it didn't seem to do much of a difference for me, other than portrait or landscape mode.

Comment: Thanks @Filip, did you happen to share the source somewhere? I actually ended up having my Azure Function call and AppService API that does the PDF rendering, but I'd love a single solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For [DinkToPdf](https://github.com/rdvojmoc/DinkToPdf), the error `Qt: Could not initialize OLE (error 80070005)` is caused by javascript tags or references. See the [test done by Travis](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/2782#issuecomment-246375337). When js is removed Function returns PDF successfully but the error message persists.

I find another lib [OpenHtmlToPdf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenHtmlToPdf/) works for Azure Function in S1(B1+ as @Filip mentioned) App service plan. Just change `BuildPdf` method from the [sample](https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2018/02/14/pdf-generation-in-azure-functions-v2.aspx) offered by @Scott. Haven't tested its performance.

```
private static byte[] BuildPdf(string html)
{
    return OpenHtmlToPdf.Pdf.From(html).Content();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jerry, I can't remove the javascript in my html doc that is used for PDF generation. At this point I'm having the Azure Function do an API call to an WebService that supports `Select.HtmlToPdf` and will probably move this functionality to a container if it still doesn't work with `netcore3.0` in a little while.

Comment: @Ovi My mistake, I should have clarified that the js tag restriction is in `DinkToPdf` not  `OpenHtmlToPdf`. Never mind, since you have found a valid solution, this can be an alternative option to try if interested. BTW, just find another package and I will do some tests. If it works, I will add it to my solution just for more people to refer. Anyway, good question!