# how to Insert my Azure function to PowerApps

Tags: c#, swagger, azure-functions, powerapps, common-data-service

With Reference to my old Thread 
[How to implement My Azure function for using it in PowerApps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60169520/how-to-implement-my-azure-function-for-using-it-in-powerapps)

Im still struggling with implementing my function to powerapps 
I dont really know what I have to do next. The function itself is already working.
But If I want to execute it over an url it does not work (401 http error)

MY Url: https://XXX.azurewebsites.net/api/XXX/?blobname1=image1.png&blobname2=image2.png

```
    [FunctionName("ConvertMe")]
public async static Task RunASync([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
  [Blob("test", FileAccess.ReadWrite)] CloudBlobContainer blobContainer,
     [Blob("test/out3.png", FileAccess.ReadWrite)] CloudBlockBlob outputBlob, ILogger log)

{

    try
    {
        ConvertMe Converter = new ConvertMe();
        MemoryStream stream1 = new MemoryStream();
        MemoryStream stream2 = new MemoryStream();
        log.LogInformation($"Containername: {blobContainer.Name} \nPublic Access: {blobContainer.Properties.PublicAccess} \nOriginal Path: {blobContainer.Uri.OriginalString}");
        string name1 = req.Query["blobname1"];
        string name2 = req.Query["blobname2"];



        CloudBlob blob1 = blobContainer.GetBlobReference(name1);
        CloudBlob blob2 = blobContainer.GetBlobReference(name2);

        await blob1?.DownloadToStreamAsync(stream1);
        stream1.Position = 0;
        await blob2?.DownloadToStreamAsync(stream2);
        stream2.Position = 0;

        MagickImage _Main = new MagickImage(stream1, MagickFormat.Png);
        MagickImage _Overlay = new MagickImage(stream2, MagickFormat.Png);

        using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Converter.ComebineBitmap(_Main, _Overlay).Write(memory, MagickFormat.Png);
            memory.Position = 0;
            outputBlob.Properties.ContentType = "image/png";

            await outputBlob?.UploadFromStreamAsync(memory);
        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception e)
    {

        log.LogError(e.Message);

    }
    finally
    {
        log.LogInformation("Wuhu ich bin durch");
    }



}
```

[image: Power Apps Example]

This is how I want to compose the images in PowerApps 
OnClick Event

"AzureFunction.ConvertMe(Input1:PictureBox.Image, Input2:PenInput; Output:CDS_Image.OUTputfield)"

So I think I dont really need blobobjects as Inputs or am I misunderstanding something ?

Im trying to follow this [guide](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/de-de/blog/using-azure-functions-in-powerapps/), but I dont really know how to build/setup the correct swagger.json for my example

Comment: Hey @wambo, I'm wondering if the answers your other questions last week actually answer this one? What is the the specific question you are asking here that you didn't ask here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60169520/how-to-implement-my-azure-function-for-using-it-in-powerapps or here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60229963/how-to-setup-swagger-for-powerapps-correctly

Comment: Im still struggling and finally found out the problem that cause all this confusing questions :P 
So this thread is deprecated because Im using the way in this thread 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60229963/how-to-setup-swagger-for-powerapps-correctly