# How to setup Swagger for PowerApps correctly?

Tags: c#, azure-functions, swagger-2.0, powerapps

This is my Azure function I want to connect to my PowerApps

```
        [FunctionName("ConvertMe")]
    public static IActionResult RunAsync
        ([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"Received a Request");
        ConvertMe Converter = new ConvertMe();

        string test1 = req.Query["image1"];
        string test2 = req.Query["image2"];


        MagickImage _Main = new MagickImage(Convert.FromBase64String(test1), MagickFormat.Png);
        MagickImage _Overlay = new MagickImage(Convert.FromBase64String(test2), MagickFormat.Png);

        using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Converter.ComebineBitmap(_Main, _Overlay).Write(memory, MagickFormat.Png);
            memory.Position = 0;
            return new FileContentResult(memory.ToArray(),"image/png");
        }

    }
```

Its already working on local but I want to use it in PowerApps. 
How do I get my return value to Swagger ?

My current swagger file

```
    {
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "title": "MyAzureFunction"
  },
  "host": "xxx",
  "paths": {
    "/api/ConvertMe": {
      "get": {
        "description": "Calls my azure function over https",
        "operationId": "ConvertMe",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "code",
            "in": "query",
            "description": "code",
            "default": "code",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "image1",
            "in": "query",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string"
          },     
          {
            "name": "image2",
            "in": "query",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string"
          },

        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Successful response",
            "schema": {
              "title": "The response of the api.",
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Ive never worked with swagger but ive already found out, the best is to work with base64 string.

Comment: So this is a json file, and your ultimate goal is to get one of these values?

Comment: No. I want to do something like this..
https://powerapps.microsoft.com/de-de/blog/using-azure-functions-in-powerapps/

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has a tutorial for [creating an OpenAPI definition from a server-less API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-openapi-definition#generate-the-openapi-definition). If you follow the steps laid out you will eventually get to the Download the [OpenAPI](https://swagger.io/blog/api-strategy/difference-between-swagger-and-openapi/) definition step, which is what you can use to [import into powerapps to make your custom connector.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/define-openapi-definition)

Comment: unfortunately. I dont have any permissions to use the api management system. :(
So I need to write it down by myself.
Im facing a problem with my function anyway. Im getting an Error 400 because the base64 strings are to big for the request. so it seems I cant work with base64 string like that.