# Split TIFF file into separate files without API on Azure c#

Tags: c#, azure, tiff

What is the best way to split a tiff file in Azure? System.Drawing cannot be used [Azure Function gives error: System.Drawing is not supported on this platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51904125/azure-function-gives-error-system-drawing-is-not-supported-on-this-platform) .

Ive read about the format specification and have tried to a seek for IFHD. But the first picture somes through and sibsequent ones are blank. No code yet just opened in notepad++ and removed everything from where the number of tags is retrieved.

Perhaps i need to offset the hex values after deletion

Comment: Please provide code on what you have tried and what has or has not worked for you, Also if you make a statement like xxxx can't be used please qualify with an explanation. Please see this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question so you get better answers.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question and include details about what you have tried so far. Please include any code that you have written.

Comment: System.Drawing is disabled on many Azure instances as it is built on top of very old umanaged code in GDI+. There are open source alternatives such as ImageSharp, Magick.NET and SkiaSharp ... source: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/how-do-you-use-systemdrawing-in-net-core