# IronPDF System.Exception Error while generating PDF from Url in Azure function

Tags: azure, pdf, azure-functions, ironpdf

I have an Azure (durable) function that is using the new Runtime Version 3 which is supposed to generate a PDF using IronPDF from a URL. The function keeps failing and the only error that gets logged to Insights is something like this:

> **Exception**: Exception while executing function: A_GetPdfDataFromUrl
>
> **Type**: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException
>
> **Stack Trace**
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException: Exception while executing function: A_GetPdfDataFromUrl
>
> ---> System.Exception: Error while generating PDF from 'https://www.myurl.com'
>
> at .(String , CefRenderSettings , CefBrowserSettings )
>
> at .RenderPdfDocumentFromUri(ChromePdfRenderOptions Options, ChromeHttpLoginCredentials Login, Uri url)
>
> at IronPdf.Rendering.Abstractions.PdfRenderProxy'2.RenderUrlAsPdf(Uri Url)
>
> at IronPdf.Rendering.Abstractions.PdfRenderProxy'2.RenderUrlAsPdf(String UrlOrPath)
>
> at IronPdf.Rendering.Abstractions.PdfRenderProxy'2.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.b__0()
>
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task'1.InnerInvoke()
>
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__274_0(Object obj)
>
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
>
> at MyFuncs.PdfFunc.GetPdfDataFromUrl(String url) in D:\a\1\s\Funcs\PdfFunc.cs:line 155
> at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker'2.InvokeAsync(Object instance, Object[] arguments) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionInvoker.cs:line 52
>
> at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.InvokeWithTimeoutAsync(IFunctionInvoker invoker, ParameterHelper parameterHelper, CancellationTokenSource timeoutTokenSource, CancellationTokenSource functionCancellationTokenSource, Boolean throwOnTimeout, TimeSpan timerInterval, IFunctionInstance instance) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:line 572
>
> at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithWatchersAsync(IFunctionInstanceEx instance, ParameterHelper parameterHelper, ILogger logger, CancellationTokenSource functionCancellationTokenSource) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:line 518
>
> at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(IFunctionInstanceEx instance, FunctionStartedMessage message, FunctionInstanceLogEntry instanceLogEntry, ParameterHelper parameterHelper, ILogger logger, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:line 296

Unfortunately, IronPDF logs dont get generated in Azure due to a bug in their current version which they said will be fixed in the next release. So until then I'm unable to figure out why this simple code is failing in Azure.

```
[FunctionName("A_GetPdfDataFromUrl")]
public async Task<byte[]> GetPdfDataFromUrl([ActivityTrigger] string url)
{
    IronPdf.License.LicenseKey = "";
    IronPdf.Logging.Logger.EnableDebugging = true;
    IronPdf.Logging.Logger.LoggingMode = IronPdf.Logging.Logger.LoggingModes.All;

    ChromePdfRenderer chromePdfRenderer = new ChromePdfRenderer();
    

    var trackReportPdf = chromePdfRenderer.RenderUrlAsPdf(url);

    return trackReportPdf.BinaryData;
}
```

Comment: Log files do get generated in Azure. See: https://iron.helpscoutdocs.com/article/122-azure-log-files
All logs are stored in block blobs in a container named $logs. This is automatically created when Storage Analytics is enabled for a storage account.
The $logs container is located in the blob namespace of the storage account, for example:

http:// .blob.core.windows.net/$logs >.blob.core.windows.net/$logs .

Comment: @darren  "...when Storage Analytics is enabled for a storage account." Do you mean the storage account that is assigned to the azure function?

Answer (score 4):

Thank you [darren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14328954/darren). Posting your suggestions as an answer to help other community members.

The logs will be generated in Azure where all the logs will be stored in a container called $logs.  The container $logs is automatically generated when the storage account is created.

> All logs are stored in **block blobs in a container named $logs.**
> This is automatically created when Storage Analytics is enabled for a storage account.
> The $logs container is located in the blob namespace of the storage account

To answer your question [Raihan-Iqbal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/188778/raihan-iqbal)

> Do you mean the storage account that is assigned to the azure function

Yes the storage account that creates when we create Azure Function or it may be any of the storage account the $logs container will be generated automatically.

For further details see [Iron Log Files](https://iron.helpscoutdocs.com/article/122-azure-log-files).