# HTML to PDF using ironPDF getting error in AZURE WEBAPP:- Error while deploying Chrome dependencies [Issue Code IRONPDF-CHROME-DEPLOYMENT-ERROR]

Tags: c#, azure, pdf, azure-deployment, ironpdf

I'm facing an issue while generating PDF from html using ironpdf on Azure web app.

This is the exception I get:

> Exception details:
>
> Error while deploying Chrome dependencies. To learn how to solve this issue please read https://iron.helpscoutdocs.com/article/166-error-while-deploying-chrome-dependencies [Issue Code IRONPDF-CHROME-DEPLOYMENT-ERROR]

I followed the steps given in documentation but not able to crack this,

Code is working fine in local environment, I'm facing the issue in Azure web app.

This is the code:

```
using IronPdf

var Renderer = new HtmlToPdf();

var PDF = Renderer.RenderHtmlAsPdf(fullhtml);
```

It is throwing the error at the last line shown - can someone guide me how to successfully deploy this to Microsoft Azure?

Comment: Several UI functionality, like Windows GDI will **not** work in the Function app sandbox environment.

Comment: Refer this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51904125/azure-function-gives-error-system-drawing-is-not-supported-on-this-platform)

Comment: IronPDF is tested on and [works in Azure](https://ironpdf.com/docs/questions/azure/) Webapp and Functions v3/v4. Please can you enable the debugging to generate log files? These will better show what is happening

Answer (score 1):

I also faced a similar kind of issue ([`Issue Code IRONPDF-CHROME-DEPLOYMENT-ERROR-MAC-X64`]).

**Exception**[image]

**Why Error** It's because of upgrading an "IRONPDF" version. I upgraded that from my windows machine so when I switch to another windows os it works well, but when I switch to mac os it throws this error.

**Solution**
You have to install a "nuget package" according to your os. For my mac os, I need to install `IronPdf.MacOs`. So I executed the below command into the .net CLI, And after this installation, it worked perfectly fine.

`dotnet add package IronPdf.MacOs --version 2022.12.11113`

Here I attach my finding for the resolution, I hope it will also work for other os.

- Source: [Error while deploying Chrome dependencies](https://iron.helpscoutdocs.com/article/166-error-while-deploying-chrome-dependencies)
- Package Source: [nuget package for **IronPdf.MacOs**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IronPdf.MacOs)

Answer (score 0):

Right click the Project --> Open Properties --> Go to Events Sections --> Copy the this path XCOPY "$(TargetDir)runtimes" "$(TargetDir)bin/runtimes" /S /E /Y /I /R /D --> paste in the post-build event section

Run it --> problem will be solved

Comment: There are no event sections shown on properties of the project or solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` app configuration from `1` to `0`.  This is not very apparent but hidden in the documentation here: https://iron.helpscoutdocs.com/article/21-azure.